# How does def keyword work in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Code -

```
class Parser {
 def parseName(String name) {
   if (name.contains(',')) {
     parts = name.split(',')
   }
 }
}
p = new Parser()
p.parseName('kshitiz,sharma')
```

Exception -

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: parts for class: Parser
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
    at
```

Here is the AST for the above script -

```
p = new Parser()
p.parseName('kshitiz,sharma')
public class script1376460726356 extends groovy.lang.Script { 
    public script1376460726356() {
    }
    public script1376460726356(groovy.lang.Binding context) {
        super.setBinding(context)
    }
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
        org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.runScript(script1376460726356, args)
    }
    public java.lang.Object run() {
        p = new Parser()
        p.parseName('kshitiz,sharma')
    }
}
public class Parser extends java.lang.Object { 
    public java.lang.Object parseName(java.lang.String name) {
        if (name.contains(',')) {
            parts = name.split(',')
        }
    }
}
```

Questions -

1. Why is there an error for `parts` and no error for `p`? I don't see `p` being defined or even being placed and accessed from `script binding`? It is just directly used in method `run()`.
2. What is `p = new Parser()` doing at the top? In Java shouldn't everything be in a class with global variables being just an illusion?
3. Does this mean `def` keyword is optional only in standalone scripts and not in user defined classes?

Comment: For practical reasons you can think as Object (eg, def myInt or Object myInt)

Answer (score 3):

I think this sums it up quite well:

[Scoping and the Semantics of def](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22)

In short, if not defined, then it's in binding (but this only applies to scripts) and scripts are the only place where you are allowed to not specify a variable before using it.

Comment: Yep. I'd like to add: when you are not using `def`, then you are pretty much `get`'ing or `set`'ing a property. Scripts overrides `getProperty` and `setProperty`, thus, you get that behavior.